# How to import contacts from google or gmail into my application android

Tags: android

I am developing an android application called Smart Address book. I want to implement the method of importing code i.e.to sync contacts of google with my application.But I am not getting the right way can any one tell the right way to sync contacts

Comment: AFAIK the contacts are already and automatically synced with google, unless the user decides otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can try exporting all contacts by acessing the contacts content provider. Then, you take a look at the [SampleSyncAdapter](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html)

You basically have to Setup an account and the syncadapter for it. 
I am really always wondering, why google is not documenting this properly.